# Probability distribution where data has 1/x chance of being >= x

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

I'm having a problem where I know what the probability distribution looks like and how it acts but don't know how to model it mathematically or if there's a name for it. Given a random variable $X$ following the distribution. We have
$$
P(X \ge x) = 1/x
$$

for any real number greater than or equal to 1. Is there an equation or a name for this distribution?

Comment: This is not a probability distribution, at least if $X$ can take any real values ?

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pareto_distribution

Comment: ... with parameters $x_{\min}=1$ and $\alpha = 1$.  It has an infinite mean

Comment: yooooo that's exactly what I was thinking. Thanks a bunch!